# Best way to handle a keyerror in a dict

Tags: python, dictionary

I would like to know the best way to handle a keyerror, when I try to get a value from a dict.

I need this because my dict holds the counts of some events. And whenever an event occurs I take the count from the dict and increment it and put it back.

I found some solutions online, but they were for some other languages. Any help is appreciated.

I am handling the keyerror exception now. Would like to know the best approach to handle a keyerror in a dictionary.

Note: This is not about counting items in a list but about handling exception when retrieving a value(that does not exist) from a dict.

Comment: what about `collections.Counter`?

Comment: Ok, I will try that. Is there something like a get("<key>","<default value>")

Comment: @MukundGandlur Try [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)

Comment: yes there is exactly [that get you're talking about](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use `dict.get` if you want to use `dict`

```
mydict[key] = mydict.get(key, 0) + 1
```

Or you can handle `KeyError`

```
try:
    mydict[key] += 1
except KeyError:
    mydict[key] = 1
```

Or you can use `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict
mydict = defaultdict(int)
mydict[key] += 1
```

Comment: `.get` would be fine, `setdefault` for mutable in-place values

Comment: .get is exactly what I was looking for.  It's nice not to have try except everywhere in the code.

Answer (score 4):

The most appropriate data structure for what you want to do is `collections.Counter`, where missing keys have an implicit value of `0`:

```
from collections import Counter
events = Counter()
for e in "foo", "bar", "foo", "tar":
    events[e] += 1
```

Answer (score 2):

[collections.defaultdict](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) could help to build a *pythonic* code:

```
count = collections.defaultdict(int) # => default value is 0
...
count[event] += 1 # will end to 1 on first hit and will increment later
```

Comment: No Counter? ... that would be more ... Pythonic.

Answer (score 0):

Exceptions in Python are not very expensive.

Plus, if you consider that most of the time the key you are looking for (the count) is there, then it is totally fine.

```
d = {}
while True:
    try:
        d['count'] += 1
    except KeyError:
        d['count'] = 1  # happens only once
```