# Why does my for loop stop before the loop is finished?

Tags: python, dictionary, for-loop

I have a for loop that is going through a dictionary with a lot of nested dictionaries. When the loop gets to an entry that doesn't have the key I am looking for it stops. How do I make it keep going through all the rest of the data?

In my code the loop goes through the games fine.
When I try to get all the game['odds'] the loop stops if one game doesn't have an odds key which ends up giving me a key error and only printing out the first four games.

```py
    results = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
    games = results['results']
    for game in games:
        spread = game['odds']
        for line in spread:
            points = line['spread']['current']['home']
            print(points)
```

Comment: well, the answer of your question - why, is in your post - "one game doesn't have an odds key which ends up giving me a key error"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Best way to handle a keyerror in a dict](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36597869/best-way-to-handle-a-keyerror-in-a-dict)

Comment: Also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10116518/im-getting-key-error-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `spread = game['odds']` with `spread = game.get('odds',[])` so that `spread` gets an empty list when there is no 'odds' key and the rest of the code will behave correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume that it stops because of a `KeyError` Here, you have two choices to overcome it.

**dict().get()**

```
d = {}
d.get('foo') #Returns None
```

The `.get()` method is handy because if the specified key doesn't exist, then it will simply return None. Use where you don't want to deal with errors raining from the sky.

**try except**

Slightly more complex.

```
try:
    raise ValueError('ya goofed m8')
except ValueError:
    print('How the tables have turned...')
```

This will listen for an error and then execute some code if that error happens
`try` is the code you want to listen for an error in.
`except` is the code for the error.

Comment: This half worked because it ended up causing a " 'NoneType' object is not iterable" error.

Answer (score -1):

Try doing this:

```
results = requests.request("GET", url, headers=headers).json()
    games = results['results']
    for game in games:
        if(game['odds']):
            spread = game['odds']
            for line in spread:
                points = line['spread']['current']['home']
                print(points)
```